# Change lock icon in xtrlock/pyxtrlock?

Tags: ubuntu, lock-screen

I am using Ubuntu 13.10, and I would like to change the blue lock icon provided by default with `xtrlock` or `pyxtrlock` (a Python version, https://github.com/leonnnn/pyxtrlock). I don't particularly care which, though I had problems compiling `xtrlock` from source whereas the other one worked.

Both of them appear to use the same format to create the icon, here is the image data from `xtrlock`'s source code, from the file `lock.bitmap`. There is also a similar file called `mask.bitmap`.  `pyxtrlock` appears to have the same icon but the data is in a single file, `make_default_lock.py`.

```
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x01, 0xf8, 0xff, 0x7f, 0x00, 0xe0, 0xff,
0x3f, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xff, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x80, 0xff, 0x0f, 0xfc, 0x03, 0xff,
0x0f, 0xfe, 0x07, 0xff, 0x0f, 0xff, 0x0f, 0xff, 0x07, 0xff, 0x0f, 0xfe,
0x87, 0xff, 0x1f, 0xfe, 0x87, 0xff, 0x1f, 0xfe, 0x87, 0xff, 0x1f, 0xfe,
0x87, 0xff, 0x1f, 0xfe, 0x87, 0xff, 0x1f, 0xfe, 0x87, 0xff, 0x1f, 0xfe,
0x87, 0xff, 0x1f, 0xfe, 0x87, 0xff, 0x1f, 0xfe, 0x87, 0xff, 0x1f, 0xfe,
0x87, 0xff, 0x1f, 0xfe, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xf8,
0x01, 0xf8, 0x01, 0xf8, 0x01, 0xf8, 0x01, 0xf8, 0x01, 0xf8, 0x01, 0xf8,
0x01, 0xf8, 0x01, 0xf8, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x01, 0x60, 0x00, 0xf8,
0x01, 0x60, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x01, 0x60, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x01, 0x60, 0x00, 0xf8,
0x01, 0x60, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x01, 0x60, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8,
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff
```

What format is this and how can I convert an image to it?

Running `file` on the "compiled" (generated by `make_default_lock.py`) version of the icon from `pyxtrlock`, `lock.pickle`, gives the result "8086 relocatable (Microsoft)", which doesn't seem to give any useful results if I look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `make_lock.py` and `repickle.py` from the `tools` directory to create a custom lock for **pyxtrlock**.

```
[user@host tools]$ ./make_lock.py lock.bmp > ~/.config/pyxtrlock/lock.pickle
[user@host tools]$ ./repickle.py ~/.config/pyxtrlock/lock.pickle
```

N.B. The lock bitmap needs to have only 2 colors.